# Get multiple form inputs values in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the response of a survey, all question answers are displayed in a while loop and in action PHP page I am not getting proper responses, I'm getting the right response for the radio button only, I'm attaching the code.

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($questions)) {
?>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">(<?php echo $i; ?>)
    <?php
        $questionid = $row['question_id'];
        $question = $row['question'];
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $questionid; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="<?php echo $question; ?>" />
    <?php echo $row['question']; ?></label>
    <div class="controls">
    <?php
        if ($row['answer_type'] == "Ratings") {
            echo "<p>
                Low<input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='1' id='rating_0'>                                                                                                         
                <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='2' id='rating_1'>                                                         
                <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='3' id='rating_2'>                                                          
                <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='4' id='rating_3'>                                                      
                <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='5' id='rating_4'>High                                                   
            </p>";
        } else if ($row['answer_type'] == "Comments") {
            echo "<textarea name='answer' cols='' rows=''></textarea>";
        }
        $i++;
        echo "<br />";
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Action file code:

```
foreach($_POST as $val){
    $query2 = "insert into review_details (review_id,survey_id,question_id,question,answer_rating,answer_freeresponse) values (1,$_SESSION[surveyid],$_POST[questionid],'$_POST[question]',$val,'$_POST[answer]')";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);                                                      

    if(!$result2) {
        echo mysqli_error($result2);
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to insert the survey answers in the MySQL table including the fields displayed in the output picture.

Comment: You should use **mysqli_stmt_prepare()**. You do not need `foreach`.

Comment: result is there in the screenshot! @blue can you please post code snippet for the same!

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` tags are missing from the exposed code, so there might be some extra fields available that are important for the scenario.

There is no obvious reason for using `foreach` on `$_POST`. You should explain further why you're cycling it.

Here is some code for your action file, that *might* work for you:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO review_details (review_id,survey_id,question_id,question,answer_rating,answer_freeresponse) VALUES(1,?,?,?,?,?)")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_SESSION['surveyid'], $_POST['questionid'], $_POST['question'], $val, $_POST['answer']);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: i guess something is missing in the code, i dont know exactly, but i tried this, doesn't work.